# Modeling a feature issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a project , trying to implement a feature :it's a playlist that will contain video objects

my associations

```
 class Video < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :playlist
  end 

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many   :playlists
  end 

  class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many   : videos
    belongs_to :user
  end
```

i have a migration that will create the playlist as an resource for the CRUD

my dilemma here , and i can't quite figure out how to implement it in the controller level,  to be able to add a video object to the user created playlist . In my thoughts process , the user created playlist should be an array and in my playlist model i will add a method that will retrieve the video and scope the playlist to the current_user and finally push it to the new array and save it .But I'm trying to make the transition from tutorial to writing a feature from scratch.

ps. i don't know if accepted_nested_attributes is a real or viable path to implement this also?
 any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :playlist
  has_one :user, through: :playlist
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlists
  has_many :videos, through: :playlists
end 

class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :videos
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Your routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :playlists do
    resources :videos
  end
end
# the generated routes:
# /users/<user_id>/edit
# /users/<user_id>/playlists/<playlist_id>/edit
# /users/<user_id>/playlists/<playlist_id>/videos/<video_id>/edit
# etc.
```

So the following URLs:

- `/users/1/playlists` will list all the playlists of the #1 User;
- `/users/1/playlists/12/videos` will list all the videos of the playlist #12

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,one more issue , how i can add a video to the playlist without created  it , i have video already created by admin and im trying to figure out how a user can select one video from the library and add it to his or her playlist.

Comment: You just need to update the playlist_id attribute of the corresponding video ;)